# SQL select remaining inventory rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help for my inventory table, this query should select the remaining rows from inventory table:

```
timestamp          Prod_id  Loc_ID  Price   Buy Sell
2017/2/21 12:24:00  50          A   10      1     0
2017/2/22 13:15:00  50          A   10      2     0
2017/2/23 14:00:00  50          A   12      0     2
2017/2/24 12:20:00  55          B   2       1     0
2017/2/25 10:04:00  55          B   2       1     0   
2017/2/26 11:44:00  55          B   5       0     3
2017/2/27 15:22:00  60          C   3       5     0
2017/2/28 16:24:00  60          C   4       0     5
```

Select result should be this:

```
timestamp          Prod_id  Loc_ID  Price   Buy Sell
2017/2/22 13:15:00  50          A   10      1     0
2017/2/26 11:44:00  55          B   5       0     1
```

Here is the code for this table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.inventory
    (
      timestamp  DATETIME2 DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL
    , Prod_id    INT NOT NULL
    , Loc_ID     nvarchar(3)
    , Price      INT NOT NULL
    , Buy      INT NOT NULL
    , Sell      INT NOT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO dbo.inventory
VALUES  ('2017-02-21 12:24:00',50,'A',10,1,0)

INSERT INTO dbo.inventory
VALUES  ('2017-02-22 13:15:00',50,'A',10,2,0)

INSERT INTO dbo.inventory
VALUES  ('2017-02-23 14:00:00',50,'A',12,0,2)

INSERT INTO dbo.inventory
VALUES  ('2017-02-24 12:20:00',55,'B',2,1,0)

INSERT INTO dbo.inventory
VALUES  ('2017-02-25 10:04:00',55,'B',2,1,0)

INSERT INTO dbo.inventory
VALUES  ('2017-02-26 11:44:00',55,'B',5,0,3)

INSERT INTO dbo.inventory
VALUES  ('2017-02-27 15:22:00',60,'C',3,5,0)

INSERT INTO dbo.inventory
VALUES  ('2017-02-28 16:24:00',60,'C',4,0,5)
```

---

Inventory2 
this query should select the remaining rows from inventory table:

```
timestamp           ord_label   prod_id Loc_ID  price   buy sell
2017/2/22 12:24:00  30411           54  72      52      2   0
2017/2/23 12:24:00  30412           54  72      53      2   0
2017/2/24 12:24:00  30413           54  72      55      0   3
2017/2/25 12:25:00  30414           56  70      42      2   0
2017/2/25 12:34:00  30415           56  70      32      2   0
2017/2/26 12:24:00  30416           56  70      62      0   4
2017/2/27 13:34:00  30417           56  77      2       2   0
2017/2/27 14:24:00  30418           56  77      4       0   1
2017/2/27 14:25:00  30419           60  80      4       0   1
```

Result should be:

```
timestamp               ord_label   prod_id Loc_ID  price   buy sell
2017/2/23 12:24:00      30412       54      72      53      1   0
2017/2/27 13:34:00      30417       56      77      2       1   0
2017/2/27 14:25:00      30419       60      80      4       0   1
```

These are the most recent rows.

(SQL code)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.inventory2
    (
      timestamp DATETIME2 DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL
    , Ord_label INT NOT NULL
    , Prod_id   INT NOT NULL
    , Loc_ID    NVARCHAR (3)
    , Price     INT NOT NULL
    , Buy       INT NOT NULL
    , Sell      INT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO dbo.inventory2
VALUES  ('2017-02-22 12:24:00',30411,54,'72',52,2,0)

INSERT INTO dbo.inventory2
VALUES  ('2017-02-23 12:24:00',30412,54,'72',53,2,0)

INSERT INTO dbo.inventory2
VALUES  ('2017-02-24 12:24:00',30413,54,'72',55,0,3)

INSERT INTO dbo.inventory2
VALUES  ('2017-02-25 12:25:00',30414,56,'70',42,2,0)

INSERT INTO dbo.inventory2
VALUES  ('2017-02-25 12:34:00',30415,56,'70',32,2,0)

INSERT INTO dbo.inventory2
VALUES  ('2017-02-26 12:24:00',30416,56,'70',62,0,4)

INSERT INTO dbo.inventory2
VALUES  ('2017-02-27 13:34:00',30417,56,'77',2,2,0)

INSERT INTO dbo.inventory2
VALUES  ('2017-02-27 14:24:00',30418,56,'77',4,0,1)

INSERT INTO dbo.inventory2
VALUES  ('2017-02-27 14:25:00',30419,60,'80',4,0,1)
```

Comment: So you want the most recent row in that table for each product, but in the buy and sell columns, it will show the required stock levels (quantity required to buy or sell)?

Comment: mssql server 2012

Comment: Hi please look at inventory2. GurV solved the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using conditional aggregations:

```
select case when sum(buy) > sum(sell) then max(case when buy > 0 then timestamp end) else max(case when sell > 0 then timestamp end) end as timestamp,
    prod_id,
    Loc_ID,
    case when sum(buy) > sum(sell) then max(case when buy > 0 then price end) else max(case when sell > 0 then price end) end as price,
    case when sum(buy) > sum(sell) then sum(buy) - sum(sell) else 0 end as buy,
    case when sum(sell) > sum(buy) then sum(sell) - sum(buy) else 0 end as sell
from dbo.inventory
group by prod_id,
    Loc_ID
having sum(buy) - sum(sell) <> 0;
```

Produces:

[image]

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/NRRSP89873)

#### EDIT:

For the latest edit in the question, you can add another case statement in the select:

```
select case when sum(buy) > sum(sell) then max(case when buy > 0 then timestamp end) else max(case when sell > 0 then timestamp end) end as timestamp,
    case when sum(buy) > sum(sell) then max(case when buy > 0 then ord_label end) else max(case when sell > 0 then ord_label end) end as ord_label,
    prod_id,
    Loc_ID,
    case when sum(buy) > sum(sell) then max(case when buy > 0 then price end) else max(case when sell > 0 then price end) end as price,
    case when sum(buy) > sum(sell) then sum(buy) - sum(sell) else 0 end as buy,
    case when sum(sell) > sum(buy) then sum(sell) - sum(buy) else 0 end as sell
from dbo.inventory2
group by prod_id,
    Loc_ID
having sum(buy) - sum(sell) <> 0;
```

Produces:

[image]

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/VGLSD63134)

#### How it works:

It takes the value from those row when has the sum greater out of sell or buy. If buy total is more than sell total, then , for e.g., we'll take max of ord_label from rows with non zero buy.

Comment: Hi GurV, thanks your query works for this table. I have another table Inventory2, it has one column more "ord_label" then this query doesn't work anymore. Can you show me the new query? And if time, please explain what the query is doing... want to understand it ;)

Comment: @Frankie - Updated the answer for your latest edit and added some explanation.

Comment: @Frankie - Please consider marking the answer accepted if it's helpful. There is no obligation to do this though